# C# what is the shortest way ( least amount of text ) to attach a function to a property setter?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a class, that needs to call a refresh function every time a property is changed. So I find myself writing a lot of these:

```
private double _x;
public double X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            _x = value;
            refresh();
        }
    }
```

The refresh function is always the same for each property.
Is there a shorter way to do this?

Also, I always access the `private double _x` through `double X`, so something like `public double X { get; set}` would work fine, if I could integrate the `refresh()` method somehow.

Comment: You can use reflection to dynamically add properties and do that for each field, but I doubt it is much shorter than writing an additional single line per property.

Comment: You may write a custom [refresher] annotation?

Comment: Are you familiar with code snippets? They can make writing repetitive code a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pure C# way is to move the repetitive code to a method.

In your case, something like this:

```
void Set<T>(ref T field, T value)
{
    field = value;
    refresh();
}
```

and the use it like this:

```
private double _x;
public double X { get { return _x; } set { Set(ref _x, value); } }
```

Answer (score 1):

theres the nuget package https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

you can easily Create a similar package for fody that will call your refresh function.